# Writing first 100 prime numbers to a file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to teach myself node.js (no javascript or real programming experience) and have hit a road block on one of the problems I am trying to solve. My goal is to write the first 100 prime numbers to txt file. Below is my code so far.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var outfile = "test.txt";
var primality = function () {
    var arr = [];
    for (var n = 2; n <= 542; n++) {
        var primeTrue = true;
        for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i === 0) {
                primeTrue = false;
            }
        }
        if (primeTrue) {
            arr.push(n);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
fs.writeFileSync(outfile, arr);
```

I was using the codecademy javascript lab to test my loop and conditions and this code does seem to work. (It is also likely not the best way to do this since I had to set my counter to stop at 542 rather than have the program stop at the 100th prime number). In any event, when I added

```
var outfile = "test.txt"
```

and

```
fs.writeFileSync(outfile, arr);
```

this did not output the 100 prime numbers to the txt file as I thought it would. I'm still on the ground floor of my learning so I greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you in advance.

Kevin

Comment: is this because you are trying to learn node.js??

Comment: Your plan is to indent the code only once it works to save time?

Comment: You are never calling `primality` to create the array of numbers. `arr` is only defined *inside* the function. You might want `fs.writeFileSync(outfile, primality());`. I recommend to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: @MESSIAH You are correct, I am trying to learn node.js using a couple books, going through codecademy's javascript track and taking a class that includes programming problems such as the one above. In general I am just trying to learn to program and have tried a couple other languages with limited sucees.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, this makes much more sense now since I was calling primality when I was testing my loop and conditions. I will read the recommended book and give your suggestion code a try later today when I get back to work on this. Thank you for taking the time to point me in the write direction.

Comment: @KDark11, you agreed with the Coursera terms, so you have to make your homework yourself :) Don't take it seriously, I'm just kidding, IMO not points or certificates are important but your knowledge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing a lot in one function. The code may be a bit easier to follow if you break it up into two functions, one to make the list of primes and another to test if a specific number is prime:

```
function listPrimes( nPrimes ) {
    var primes = [];
    for( var n = 2;  nPrimes > 0;  n++ ) {
        if( isPrime(n) ) {
            primes.push( n );
            --nPrimes;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

function isPrime( n ) {
    var max = Math.sqrt(n);
    for( var i = 2;  i <= max;  i++ ) {
        if( n % i === 0 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can run it in Node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync( 'test.txt', listPrimes(100) );
```

or directly in the browser console:

```
listPrimes( 100 );
```

(I didn't test the code in Node, only in the browser.)

A couple of related notes:

1. The `sqrt()` calculation is moved outside the loop in `isPrime()`, so it doesn't have to be recalculated for each number you're testing.
2. The `nPrimes` variable lets you generate the exact number of primes you want without the `542` hack.

Having written this simple version, it's interesting to look at possible optimizations. One is to check for divisibility only on the previously generated primes, instead of checking all integers up to the square root. You could do that like this:

```
function listPrimes( nPrimes ) {
    var primes = [];
    for( var n = 2;  nPrimes > 0;  n++ ) {
        if( isPrime( n, primes ) ) {
            primes.push( n );
            --nPrimes;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

function isPrime( n, primes ) {
    var max = Math.sqrt(n);
    for( var i = 0;  i < primes.length  &&  primes[i] <= max;  i++ ) {
        if( n % primes[i] === 0 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That may be faster if you're generating a large number of primes, although for 100 of them it hardly matters and I'd be inclined to stick with the simpler code.

Of course if you're talking about optimization, it's always worth considering a different algorithm. The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a fun one because it's fast and fairly simple and easy to understand. That Wikipedia article has a great illustration of how it works. In JavaScript it might look something like this:

```
function listPrimes( max ) {
    // Start with an empty list of primes
    var primes = [];
    // Initialize the sieve - each number is prime unless proven otherwise
    var sieve = new Array( max );
    for( var i = 1;  i <= max;  i++ ) {
        sieve[i] = true;
    }
    // Now check each number from 2 through max
    for( var p = 2;  p <= max;  p++ ) {
        if( sieve[p] ) {
            // p is prime, save it in the output list
            primes.push( p );
            // Mark p * 2, p * 3, p * 4, etc. as non-prime
            for( var t = p * 2;  t <= max;  t += p ) {
                sieve[t] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Yes, after recommending splitting the code into two functions, I'm now back to one function. :-)

One difference about the Sieve is that you can't really say, "please give me the first N primes"; instead you ask it, "please give me all the primes less than N". But if N is a large number, it is much faster than the other approach.

Comment: Michael, I appreciate the detail that went into this and your thoughts about simpler code make perfect sense. I am reading the chapter recommended by another user and then I will come back to my code and your suggested code to better understand how I could have written this better. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad that was useful for you. That's what we're all here for, to help each other out. I would say that for someone with "no javascript or real programming experience" you are off to a great start!

Comment: @MichaelGeary like the optimization

Answer (score 3):

This works even beter if you preinitialize the list and skip testing the primality of multiples of 2

```
var primes = [2];
--nPrimes
for( var n = 3;  nPrimes > 0;  n += 2 )
```

I just finished very similar code for the Startup Engineering course homework @Coursera ;)